# Creating an Epic from a Github Issue with Zenhub API

Tags: python, github, zenhub

This is a follow up question to [How to set an issue pipeline with zenhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860744/how-to-set-an-issue-pipeline-with-zenhub-api).

I'm attempting to convert an issue to an epic in a Python script. I can convert the issue to an Epic, but I get an error when I attempt to add issues when creating the epic.

This works:

```
zenhub_headers = {"X-Authentication-Token": "%s" % token}
target_zh_issues_url = '%s/p1/repositories/%d/issues' % (zh_api_endpoint, target_repo_id)
params = {}
response = requests.post(target_zh_issues_url + '/%s/convert_to_epic' % issue, headers=zenhub_headers, data=params)
```

The code also works when I set `params = {"issues":[]}`

But when I attempt to add an issue with `params = {"issues": [{"repo_id": 280565, "issue_number": 17}]}`

I get a 400 error, `b'{"message":"Invalid Field for issues: [object Object],[object Object]"}'`

I then tried using the `/update_issues` API to add issues to the epics I'd created.

```
target_zh_epics_url = '%s/p1/repositories/%d/epics' % (zh_api_endpoint, target_repo_id)
params = {"add_issues": [{"repo_id": 280565, "issue_number": 17}]}
response = requests.post(target_zh_epics_url + '/%s/update_issues' % issue, headers=zenhub_headers, data=params)
```

This resulted in a 400 error, `b'{"message":"Invalid Field for addIssues: repo_id,issue_number"}'`. Those fields are as described in the [API doc](https://github.com/ZenHubIO/API#add-or-remove-issues-to-epic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to my headers and dumping the JSON body to a string, `params = json.dumps({"issues": [{"repo_id": 280565, "issue_number": 17}]})`

My code now looks like:

```
zenhub_headers = {"X-Authentication-Token": "%s" % token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
target_zh_issues_url = '%s/p1/repositories/%d/issues' % (zh_api_endpoint, target_repo_id)
params = json.dumps({"issues": [{"repo_id": 280565, "issue_number": 17}]})
response = requests.post(target_zh_issues_url + '/%s/convert_to_epic' % issue, headers=zenhub_headers, data=params)
```

Though I'm not sure why the call with a body of unstringified `{"issues":[]}` was succeeding.