# Failed to add issues to release report by REST API

Tags: zenhub

I'm writing a program about create issues on gitHub. When I try to set the issue's release-date by using [this API](https://github.com/ZenHubIO/API#add-or-remove-issues-to-or-from-a-release-report), I got a 400 response.

I tried different kinds of data(even empty issue list), but none of them worked.

part of my code:

```
self.host = config.get_str('zen_hub_host')
self.headers = {
    'X-Authentication-Token': config.get_str('zen_hub_token'),
}

....

response = self.session.patch(f'{self.host}'                                                   
                              f'p1/reports/release/{release_id}/issues',
                              json.dumps(data),headers=self.headers)
```

PS: I've checked host, token and release_id by trying 'GET /p1/reports/release/:release_id/issues'.

Error Message is : 'Invalid request , invalid issue in add_issues'.

I tried to set `add_issues` an empty list and add some issues to `remove_issues` but the error message did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. A different question but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243820/creating-an-epic-from-a-github-issue-with-zenhub-api) fixed my problem:

Problem solved by adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to my headers